# SSMS Showing diff error message in 2008 and 2014 on Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, ssms, unique-constraint

While inserting a record to my table `table1` in `SQL Server 2008` instance, I'm getting the following error

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_table1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table1'.

But while executing the same query in `SQL Server 2014` (copy of the above database), I am getting some difference in the error messsage

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_table1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table1'.
>   The duplicate key value is (xxx, ).

In **2014** the error message specifies the duplicated value in the message (`The duplicate key value is xxx`), but in **2008 it does not**.

Why this? Is this a new feature on 2014? or there is any settings to change/format the error messages?

Comment: Please post your table structure and key constraints for both environments.

Comment: What are the definitions of `PK_AsrAssetMst` and `IX_AsrAssetMst`?

Comment: They just configured the error messages differently, as you can see in 2014 it even specified the value that raised the trigger, but its the exact same error.

Comment: sorry, the question is modified. plz chk now. In 2014 is specified the duplicated valu in the message but 2008 not

Comment: As @sagi said then, it's the same error with extra information on what the duplicate key value is.

Comment: Why do you care what the error message says? Surely you're not using string comparison to detect this particular error? Since you're not particularly clear *what* you want done here I'm going to assume you either want SQL Server 2008 to also report which value was attempted inserted, or you want SQL Server 2014 to *not* report it. Either way you cannot change this but it should be unnecessary. The error message should not be shown to the user, in which case it does not matter what it says, you also know the value since you just tried to insert it, and the error code is 2627, in both cases.

Comment: But we should know, why diff instances behave like this. We should care about our server (this may be version diff, configuration diff or may some fault from my side). May it is not a silly

Comment: They changed the error message in 2014 (or an interim version) to contain more information. Your question is how to reconfigure or format the error messages. If you want to know *why* the difference exists you must likely ask the SQL Server team.

Comment: Actually my question is not to configure, but Why this diff?  (is there any do reference for *They changed the error message in 2014* @Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: Down voters, plz check the answer of  Remus Rusanu :) We got a new lesson here. and this feature is Very helpful , while inserting Set of data / bulk insert as mentioned by @Remus Rusanu,

Comment: If the question asks "can I change this" and the answer says "this was changed because" then the down-votes are correct. If the correct answer to the question *does not answer the question* then the question is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108159/discussion-between-abdul-rasheed-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Comment: can any one please add a reference / link for :  *In SQL Server 2014 there was an improvement to capture the duplicate key*, Thanks in adv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a big demand from users that when the PK violation occurs, to display the value that crated the conflict. When the violation occurs in a simple `INSERT` statement that inserts one row then is a no brainer, the violation occurred due to the value being inserted. But `INSERT` can insert also a set, eg. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM...` and then is much harder to figure out *which* row from the set caused the violation.

In SQL Server 2014 there was an improvement to capture the duplicate key that caused the violation and display it in the error message.

Comment: Hi, can u plz add a reference / link for *In SQL Server 2014 there was an improvement to capture the duplicate key*. Thanx in adv